# ¿Cómo conseguir exponer el valor del índice de un array de PHP en un echo?

Tags: php

Tengo un array de este tipo:

```
array(31) {

  ["2018-01-15"]=>
  float(13585.9013)
  ["2018-01-16"]=>
  float(11348.02)
  ["2018-01-17"]=>
  float(11141.2488)
  ["2018-01-18"]=>
  float(11250.6475)
  ["2018-01-19"]=>

etc..
```

Para conseguir el valor `float` hago:

```
foreach ($array as $item)  {
    echo $item;
}
```

¿Cómo puedo conseguir la fecha, lo que creo que viene ser ´el indice´ del array dentro del búcle? Este es el output esperado:

```
2018-01-18
11250.6475
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Es sencillo, forma parte de la sintaxis del [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

```
foreach ($array as $key => $item)  {
    echo $key. " => ". $item;
}
```

Comment: Bravo! :DD yo buscaba soluciones raras y ahi estaba.. gracias!

Comment: De nada, a veces esta en la solucion mas sencilla, como dice la navaja de ockham n.n